# При команде docker-compose up проект не запускается и выдаёт ошибку

Tags: php, python, flask, docker-compose

есть код docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  items-service:
    build: ./items
    volumes:
      - ./items:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 5001:80

  php-website:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - ./website-php:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    depends_on:
      - items-service
```

при `docker-compose up` выдаёт ошибку:

````
ERROR: for lesson-3_items-service_1  Cannot create container for service items-service: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Filesharing has been cancelled","StackTrace":"   в Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<DoShareAsync>d__6.MoveNext() в C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:строка 0\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<ShareAsync>d__4.MoveNext() в C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:строка 47\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в Docker.HttpApi.Controllers.FilesharingController.<ShareDirectory>d__2.MoveNext() в C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.HttpApi\\Controllers\\FilesharingController.cs:строка 21\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из 
предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"}

ERROR: for items-service  Cannot create container for service items-service: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Filesharing has been cancelled","StackTrace":"   в Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<DoShareAsync>d__6.MoveNext() в C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:строка 0\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в Docker.ApiServices.Mounting.FileSharing.<ShareAsync>d__4.MoveNext() в C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.ApiServices\\Mounting\\FileSharing.cs:строка 47\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n 
  в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в Docker.HttpApi.Controllers.FilesharingController.<ShareDirectory>d__2.MoveNext() в C:\\workspaces\\stable-2.3.x\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.HttpApi\\Controllers\\FilesharingController.cs:строка 21\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---\r\n   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"}
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.```

Помогите её решить!!
````

Comment: Это не вопрос, а предложение решить вашу проблему за вас гадая на кофейной гуще ответа ошибки. У нас такие запросы не приветствуются, почитайте [Справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) о том, как задавать вопросы на которые вы получите ответ(ы).

Comment: Вот видите, в выходные чего только не приключается. Глядишь, ещё выяснится что и в лотерее выиграли!